# (Android-Mapbox)Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android, mapbox-android-maps

I am trying the implement the navigation API of Mapbox into my android application. However, I have encountered the following issue:

**Failed to resolve: com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.3.0**

May I have your advise for my case please? Thanks.

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/get-started/install/

Referring to the installation guide, I have already created both public token and secret token(with DOWNLOAD:READ scope checked) and updated the build.gradle(both project and module levels), gradle.properties and the string.xml accordingly, but the implementation did not complete successfully.

Best Regards,

Frank

**My Android Studio Version**
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4

The followings are the sections extracted from my project gradles:

**build.gradle(project level)**

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
                authentication {
                    basic(BasicAuthentication)
                }
                credentials {
                    // Do not change the username below.
                    // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                    username = "mapbox"
                    // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                    password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
                }
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

**build.gradle(module level)**

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
    }

    android {
        compileSdk 32

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.xxx.main"
            minSdk 21
            targetSdk 32
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }

    dependencies {

        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
        ...
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.2.0'
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:7.0.0'
        implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9:0.9.0'
        implementation "com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.3.0"
        ...
    }
```

**gradle.properties**

```
    MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=sk.xxxx
```

**string.xml**

```
    <string name="mapbox_access_token">pk.xxxx</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just installed mapbox-navigation and this is what my settings look like

Follow these updates :

#1 your build.gradle(project level) becomes

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
      
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}



task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

your build.gradle(module level) is fine

#2 add this below line to your **settings.gradle** , right above the property *rootProject.name = "your-app-name"*

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
        credentials {
            // Do not change the username below.
            // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
            username = "mapbox"
            // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
            password = MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN
        }
    }
}}
```